# Date - time issue on timevis in shiny app in R

Tags: r, shiny, posix, utc, posixct

I have a shiny app which I would like to use the `timevis` package for Gantt chart :

```
library(timevis)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textAreaInput("addText", "Add item:", "service: \n Cost: "),
  dateInput("addDate", NULL, Sys.Date()),
  textAreaInput("group", "Add group:", "Owner:"),
  actionButton("addBtn", "Add"),
  timevisOutput("timelineInteractive"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data_rv <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(start = as.POSIXct(character(), tz = "UTC"), 
                                              end = as.POSIXct(character(), tz = "UTC"), 
                                              content = character(), 
                                              group = character(), 
                                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                            userUpdated = FALSE)
  
  groups <- reactive({
    if(nrow(data_rv$data) == 0) {
      NULL
    } else {
      data.frame(id = unique(data_rv$data$group), 
                 content = unique(data_rv$data$group))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addBtn, {
    new_item <- data.frame(start = as.POSIXct(input$addDate, tz = "UTC"),
                           end = NA,
                           content = gsub("\n", "<br>", input$addText),
                           group = input$group,
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    data_rv$data <- rbind(data_rv$data, new_item)
    data_rv$userUpdated <- FALSE
  })
  
  output$timelineInteractive <- renderTimevis({
    config <- list(
      editable = TRUE,
      multiselect = TRUE
    )
    timevis(data = data_rv$data, groups = groups(), options = config)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$timelineInteractive_data, {
    if (!data_rv$userUpdated) {
      timeline_data <- input$timelineInteractive_data
      
      timeline_data$start <- as.POSIXct(timeline_data$start, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz = "UTC")
      if ("end" %in% names(timeline_data)) {
        timeline_data$end <- as.POSIXct(timeline_data$end, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz = "UTC")
      } else {
        timeline_data$end <- NA
      }
      
      timeline_data <- timeline_data[ , c("start", "end", "content", "group")]
      names(timeline_data) <- c("start", "end", "content", "group")
      
      data_rv$userUpdated <- TRUE
      
      data_rv$data <- timeline_data
    } else {
      data_rv$userUpdated <- FALSE
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data <- input$timelineInteractive_data
    data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

App is working but it is not getting the correct date :( !
Whatever I pick from `dateInput` is going to appear both on `timevis` and table, a day before at 22:00:00 ! and I have no idea how to fix it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: While, as also given in your code, all timestamps are given in `UTC`, the app displays them in local time. You can solve this problem by converting the `start` and `end` values in the desired time zone. The following should work using `lubridate::with_tz` with `tzone = Sys.timezone()`.

```
library(timevis)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textAreaInput("addText", "Add item:", "service: \n Cost: "),
    dateInput("addDate", NULL, Sys.Date()),
    textAreaInput("group", "Add group:", "Owner:"),
    actionButton("addBtn", "Add"),
    timevisOutput("timelineInteractive"),
    tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data_rv <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(start = as.POSIXct(character(), tz = "UTC"), 
                                                end = as.POSIXct(character(), tz = "UTC"), 
                                                content = character(), 
                                                group = character(), 
                                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                              userUpdated = FALSE)
    
    groups <- reactive({
        if(nrow(data_rv$data) == 0) {
            NULL
        } else {
            data.frame(id = unique(data_rv$data$group), 
                       content = unique(data_rv$data$group))
        }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$addBtn, {
        new_item <- data.frame(start = lubridate::with_tz(as.POSIXct(input$addDate, tz = "UTC"), tzone = Sys.timezone()),
                               end = NA,
                               content = gsub("\n", "<br>", input$addText),
                               group = input$group,
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        
        data_rv$data <- rbind(data_rv$data, new_item)
        data_rv$userUpdated <- FALSE
    })
    
    output$timelineInteractive <- renderTimevis({
        config <- list(
            editable = TRUE,
            multiselect = TRUE
        )
        timevis(data = data_rv$data, groups = groups(), options = config,
                timezone = 0)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$timelineInteractive_data, {
        if (!data_rv$userUpdated) {
            timeline_data <- input$timelineInteractive_data
            
            timeline_data$start <- lubridate::with_tz(as.POSIXct(timeline_data$start, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz = "UTC"),
                                             tzone = Sys.timezone())
            if ("end" %in% names(timeline_data)) {
                timeline_data$end <- lubridate::with_tz(as.POSIXct(timeline_data$end, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz = "UTC"),
                                                        tzone = Sys.timezone())
            } else {
                timeline_data$end <- NA
            }
            
            timeline_data <- timeline_data[ , c("start", "end", "content", "group")]
            names(timeline_data) <- c("start", "end", "content", "group")
            
            data_rv$userUpdated <- TRUE
            
            data_rv$data <- timeline_data
        } else {
            data_rv$userUpdated <- FALSE
        }
    })
    
    output$table <- renderTable({
        data <- input$timelineInteractive_data
        data
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```